# How can I get past corruption?

Tags: terraria

I have a golden pickaxe and mostly complete golden armor.  I also have an enchanted boomerang.  I'd like to go find the dungeon, but while I can make short work of most individual monsters, I can't get past the swarms of monsters that descend on me whenever I reach the corruption that exists on either side of my spawn.  I've tried running past them, but there are some hills and I'm not able to build sufficiently to get up over them.

Do I need to tunnel under the corruption (I can't tunnel through)?  Do I need a to build a skybridge over it?  Or is there some trick to dealing with the large swarms of creatures that quickly develop in trying to pass through corruption?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The enchanted boomerang can be difficult to use against the various Eaters that will swarm you in the Corruption. It's not quite fast enough to take them all out before they overwhelm you or knock you back into one of the many caverns. They like to surround and swarm you very closely.

For traversing the Corruption quickly, I'd recommend:

- The [Shiny Red Balloon](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Shiny_Red_Balloon), [Cloud in a Bottle](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Cloud_in_a_Bottle), and/or the [Rocket Boots](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Rocket_Boots) to help you handle jumping over the caverns and over the hills. Mobility is key if you want to outrun the [Eaters](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Eater_of_Souls).
- A [sword](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Sword) or other melee weapon to quickly break through the thorn-type plants that hurt you and knock you back and to take care of the Eaters. The Big Eaters have 45 max health, so having one that does enough damage to kill them in 2-3 hits is helpful. Breaking down the thorns will also increase the speed at which you can climb the hills.
- Ranged weapons with a high recast time such as [bows](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Bow) and [arrows](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Arrow), [flails](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Flails), or spells like the [Vilethorn](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Vilethorn) can be handy in trying to keep the Eaters away from you, but I've found that if you stick around too long in one place, you will get swarmed anyway and need to use the melee weapons for a quicker takedown.
- A [Grappling Hook](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Grappling_Hook) or [Ivy Whip](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Ivy_Whip) in case you fall. If you don't have a [Lucky Horseshoe](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Lucky_Horseshoe), it's very likely you will splat, as the caverns are usually very deep in the Corruption.
- When I first crossed, I kept a bunch of [Wood Platforms](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Wood_platforms) on me so I could build them over the caverns. This makes re-crossing later on much easier and faster, as you can just run over the caverns, and you won't get knocked into them by the Eaters.

Tunneling under the corruption would be incredibly time consuming, and I'm not sure how far the Ebonstone goes down in your world, so you may not be able to quickly do it at all. Tunneling through Ebonstone would require either a [Nightmare](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Nightmare_Pickaxe)/[Molten](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Molten_Pickaxe) Pickaxe, or a [Dryad](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Dryad) to sell you [Purification Powder](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Purification_Powder) so you could mine through it with lesser pickaxes. A skybridge would be less time consuming and is also a viable option, but keep in mind that if you have a [Meteorite](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Meteorite) fall later on, if it hits a skybridge, your crash site will end up with only a few blocks of Meteorite. :(

If you can't handle the Corruption right now, the Dungeon and Skeletron are probably a bit too difficult at the moment with your current gear. If you haven't yet, focus on taking down the [Eye of Cthulu](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Eye_of_cthulu) and [Eater of Worlds](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Eater_of_Worlds) so you can make [Demonite gear](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Demonite), which will prepare you better for the dungeon. Remember that the Eater of Worlds' individual segments also drop [Shadow Scales](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Shadow_Scale), so even if you fail in completely killing him, you should be able to get at least a few drops.

Comment: I have had meteors go through my sky bridge and leave as many meteorite blocks on the ground as they would had I not had a sky bridge. I don't know if the material the bridge is made out of affects its interaction with meteors but "few meteorite blocks" isn't always the outcome. Other than that good answer.

Comment: @Bravo Ah, I've never had a meteorite survive through a sky bridge and all mine are made of single line of dirt. :/ Every time, they hit the bridge and just leave behind a gaping hole and a few blocks, but nothing on the ground.

Comment: Dynamite is pretty effective at blasting through ebonstone.  So digging through them might not be so much of a problem if you can afford it.

Comment: @Jeff That's true but I imagine if you're that early in the game, you don't have as much gold to toss around. The Wikia article on [Ebonstone](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Ebonstone) compares the 3 methods; it's mostly up to player taste and what your funds/resources are.

Answer (score 7):

Don't listen to the party poopers here.

The only thing you need to get past the corruption is gumption and a bit of luck:

1. Run
2. Jump
3. ???
4. Profit

Of course, one thing that is *really* useful is a hookshot. (Made from a hook and three iron chains.) It'll let you quickly scale hills on your way through the corruption.

Of course, to be a bit of a party pooper myself:

If you can't handle the monsters in the Corruption, you probably aren't ready for the dungeon anyway. I'm sorry if that sounds a bit harsh, but such is life.

Comment: Dungeon has a ton more enemies spawning than the corruption.

Comment: @DHayes: Indeed it does.

Answer (score 3):

Get better gear. You could, of course, try to bypass the Corruption by [purifying](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Purification_Powder) or building over or under it, but if you can't get through the Corruption, then you don't stand a chance against the Dungeon and its protector.

Your next step would be the boss fights with the [Eye of Cthulhu](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Eye_of_Cthulhu) and the [Eater of Worlds](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Eater_of_Worlds) to acquire [Demonite](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Demonite_Ore) (and possibly [Meteorite](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Meteorite)) gear. The Eater of Worlds fight requires you to venture into (and fight in) the Corruption, but there isn't really a way around that. It's probably the biggest difficulty spike in the game right now.

If you're dead set on skipping it though, building a solid bridge over it (and effectively encasing the Corruption below) would be the most effective way. Purifying every "evil" block with surface contact ([like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayeUc.jpg)) is also viable, but you will, of course, need a [Dryad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayeUc.jpg) first — and 2-3 Gold Coins to spend on the powder.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way would be to mine under. Worst enemy you'll encounter is worms. If you occasionally block off your tunnel or add a door, zombies and slimes won't pester you. Corruption enemies only spawn on embonstone or corrupt grass; make sure you don't hit any of that stuff and you'll be alright.

But seriously, mine and at least get full gold or you'll have trouble doing anything harder than zombies and eyes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gold pickaxe, I would recommend waiting for a meteor to land and harvesting meteorite to make a sword or some armor before going in.

Comment: You need to mine at least one shadow orb before meteors can fall.

Answer (score 0):

Digging under would be brilliant but incredibly time consuming. it would help a lot if you don't want to let it spread in your world in hardmode. (but there are 2-4 corruptions in a world it would take for ever)

Answer (score -1):

If you have some bombs you can blow up ebonstone and building a bridge with them because only people with nightmare picks or higher can mine it so yeah that could work.